# How to get csrf token in native application for Django web

Tags: c#, python, django, unity-game-engine

I am developing Unity application.
I want to login to Django web site.

When web develop web site in Django,
we just `<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}` the code in the template.

But, native application don't know how to get the csrf token.

Could you tell me the csrf token or how to create in C# of Unity?

Comment: typically you can also get the CSRF_TOKEN from the cookies sent back from the server, so on a GET request from C# should contain the token that you can then use later on POST requests from C#

Comment: ah, I see. I just must use GET.

Comment: first request is GET (to get a valid token), then all other requests that require POST data, can use that token.

Comment: Thank you, just I get toke by `GET`? csrf token is just generated random strings isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a X-CSRFToken header to pass the token and a csrftoken cookie to get an actual token value. This might require some adjustments in the Django application.

Details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: thank you for replying.
But, I'd like to get from native application like PC, Mac, Android and iOS.